# I'm trying to make 2d array, pass it to function and then update the modified array in main

Tags: c, pointers, types, segmentation-fault

The compiler shows:

```
Warning: passing argument 1 of 'fun' from incompatible
pointer type; note: expected 'int ()[5]' but argument
is of type 'int (*)[5][5]'
```

Code:

```
#include<stdio.h>

void fun(int * b[][5])
{

    int x=11,y=90;
    printf("here");
    *b[1][3] = x;
    *b[3][1] = y;
    *b[2][2] = x + ++y;
}

int main()
{

    int a[5][5];
    a[1][3] = 12;
    a[3][1] = 145;
    fun(&a);

    printf("%d %d %d",a[1][3],a[3][1],a[2][2]);
}
```

Comment: Would help if you tagged your question with the relevant language...

Comment: Would also help if you included an actual question.

Answer (score 3):

You do not need the asterisk in your function parameters, and you don't need to dereference the array b in your function. Arrays are passed by reference (so get rid of the ampersand in foo(&a) as well), because C treats them as pointers to the first element in the sequence.

Multidimensional arrays are treated as arrays of pointers to the start of smaller sub-arrays, i.e. arrays-of-arrays. Same explanation as above applies.

Your code should look like this in the end:

```
void fun(int b[][5]) // can also be (int (*b)[5]), i.e. array of 5 pointers
{
    int x=11,y=90;
    b[1][3] = x;
    b[3][1] = y;
    b[2][2] = x + ++y;
}

int main()
{ // ...
    fun(a);
  // ...
}
```

Comment: -1 until you remove the blasphemous "arrays are pointers"...!

Comment: Removed -1.  However "arrays are passed by reference" doesn't really tell the whole picture either.

Comment: how would you put it, then? I'm happy to amend my answer.

Comment: I would say "when an array is used as argument to a function, it decays into a pointer to its first element".  I appreciate the difference is subtle, but it's important.

Answer (score 2):

```
 int a[5][5]; //is an 2d int array
```

When arrays are passed to a function, what really gets passed is a pointer to the arrays first element.

So calling the `fun()` function with `fun(a)` will actually pass the pointer to the `a` first element, in this case an int array of size 5. The function `fun()` will receive a pointer to an int array of size 5, that is to say `int (*b)[5]`. Note that `int *b[5]` is not the same and is an array of size 5 containing int pointers.

Your `fun` function can either have:

```
void fun(int b[][5])
```

or

```
void fun(int (*b)[5])
```

The first way to do it says that the function will receive a 2d array of ints, but since we know that what actually will be sent to the function is a pointer to the first element of the array `a`, the compiler will quietly compile the function as if the parameter were a pointer, since it's a pointer that it will receive.

The second way to do it explicitly shows what type it will receive, a pointer to an array of size 5.

Comment: +1: This is the most correct answer so far.  My only issue is with "the first way says that the function will receive a 2d array"; it doesn't say that, it just superficially looks like it does.